# How can I make that function wait for another function to complete?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two function :

```
this.initData(resp.Id, "")
this.initSelection(resp.results)
```

I need that initSelection function will fire only after initData function will finish,
i.e. initSelection function wait for initData  to complete.

Here how I try to achive it:

```
of(this.initData(resp.results.communityId)).subscribe(()=>this.initCustomerSelection(resp.results))
```

But the code above not doing the job.

How can I make that initSelection function wait for initData to complete?

Comment: This depends on what initData and initSelection return. It looks like `initData` doesn't return an Observable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `initData` and `initSelection` returns an observable, you can try using a `switchMap`

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.initData(resp.Id, "").pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.initSelection(resp.results),
).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

If they return promises, you can `await` them.

```
async method() {
  await this.initData(resp.Id, ""); // wait for this promise to finish before going to next line
  await this.initSelection(resp.results);
}
```

Comment: Ali, thanks for the post. The function does not return nothing. They just make initialization of the properties by HTTP calls inside the functions

Comment: To get what you want, you will have to refactor the methods to return promises or observables for them to go in order.